# How to use next/previous button without redirecting to the php files?

Tags: php, html, pagination

I need help with my code as of now i have this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5yJL.png
this is my table, it wont display any row until someone will press the search button,. if they did it will display this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TpGG.png
a list of row from database with pages, my problem is when i click the page it will display like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S4Nl.png it wont stay in the current page but redirect to the php files and i dont have any idea on what to do, the button is working btw, and it show the next right table in each page

here is my code for the page button

```
if($page>1)
 {
 echo "<a href='/api2/allrecords.php?page=".($page-1)."' class='btn btn-danger'>Previous</a>";
 }            
 for($i=1;$i<$total_page;$i++)
 {
 echo "<a href='/api2/allrecords.php?page=".$i."' class='btn btn-primary'>$i</a>";
      }
  if($i>$page)
  {
  echo "<a href='/api2/allrecords.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='btn btn-danger'>Next</a>";
  }
```

and here is for the sql

```
 if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    else
    {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $num_per_page = 20;
    $start_from = ($page-1)*02;


     $connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "crudDBck69t", "NTCHilrXdf", "crudDBck69t"); 
      $output = '';  
      
           $query = "  
           SELECT * FROM rvtable limit $start_from,$num_per_page
      ";      
            $pr_query = "select * from rvtable";
            $pr_result = mysqli_query($connect,$pr_query);
             $total_record = mysqli_num_rows($pr_result );
             $total_page = ceil($total_record/$num_per_page);
      
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

there are all in the same php files call
allrecord.php, but im displaying it on wordpress page.,

this is how i call it in my costume page template in wordpress

```
if(from_date == '' && to_date == '' && search == '')   {
                    $.ajax({  
                          url:"/api2/allrecords.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, search:search},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#rvoucher').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });
                    
                }
```

and its working well except the page button, should i change the link on it? but the $_GET is on allrecord.php file
any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the POST data is not sent together with your GET request when the user clicks the link that is the next page button.

One solution could be to instead of using links where the href reloads the page use links that have a click event listener that would run your POST request again but only this time with the page selected.

Another thing, you shouldn't really be taking use input and putting it directly into your SQL queries as that exposes you solution to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

example of how to output buttons that should reload the table with the search data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gotoPage(page) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"/api2/allrecords.php?page=" + page,
            method:"POST",
            data: {
                from_date: atob("<?php echo base64_encode($_POST['from_date'] ?? ''); ?>"),
                to_date: atob("<?php echo base64_encode($_POST['to_date'] ?? ''); ?>"),
                search: atob("<?php echo base64_encode($_POST['search'] ?? ''); ?>"),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#rvoucher').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<?php
if ($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="gotoPage(' . $page-1 . ')" class="btn btn-danger">Previous</a>';
}
for($i=1; $i < $total_page; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="gotoPage(' . $i . ')" class="btn btn-primary">' . $i . '</a>';
}
if($page < $total_page) {
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="gotoPage(' . $page+1 . ')" class="btn btn-danger">Next</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks its working now, but why my active css code is not working? still have the same color even though i remove the btn class

Comment: @Ace can you add a snippet of where you include you style to the page?
also is it the `/api2/allrecords.php` file that includes the style for the table?